# Redefining for loops with the preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am looking to do something somewhat evil. I want to redefine for loops to modify the conditional. Is there any way to do this?

From the GCC documentation, redefining keywords is supported: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html

What I'm trying to do is make a "probabilistic" wrapper for C++, to see if I can make anything interesting with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#define P 0.85

#define RANDOM_FLOAT  ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)

#define RANDOM_CHANCE (RANDOM_FLOAT < P)

#define if(a) if((a) && RANDOM_CHANCE)

#define while(a) while((a) && RANDOM_CHANCE)


// No more for loops or do-while loops
#define do
#define goto

// Doesn't work :(
//#define for(a) for(a) if(!RANDOM_CHANCE) { break; } 


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    //Should output a random list of Y's and N's
    for(int i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
        if(i < 100) {
            std::cout << "Y";
        } else {
            std::cout << "N";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Will loop for a while then terminate
    int j = 0;
    while(j < 100) {
        ++j;
        std::cout << j << "\n";
    }

   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

A perhaps more legitimate use would be to count the number of loop iterations in a running program, for example by mapping

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
```

to

```
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i, ++global_counter)
```

Is it possible to accomplish what I am trying to do?

---

EDIT: Thanks for the responses - I really appreciate it!

One of the things I can do with this is simulate a fair coin (effectively force P to be 0.5), by noting that if you have a biased coin, Pr(HT) == Pr(TH). I didn't discover this trick, but it's useful. So that means that you can approximate any probability distribution for P.

```
bool coin() {
  bool c1 = false;
  bool c2 = false;

  if(true) {
    c1 = true;
  }
  if(true) {
    c2 = true;
  }

  //If they have different faces.
  bool valid = (c1 && !c2) || (!c1 && c2);
  bool result = c1;

  if(valid) { return result; }

  return coin();
}
```

Comment: This is awesome... on like so many different levels...

Comment: If anyone else might need to maintain your code, make sure they don't know where you live.

Comment: I promise that this won't end up in production. Probably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried adding an `else` to your `for` loop? That should make it work.

```
#define for(a) for(a) if(!RANDOM_CHANCE) { break; } else

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // do something
}

/* should roughly compile to:
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) if(!RANDOM_CHANCE) { break; } else
{
    // do something
}

or (differing only in whitespace):

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    if(!RANDOM_CHANCE)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }
*/
```

Comment: +1 I was about to click the *Post* button with the exact same answer.

Answer (score 4):

You showed it already. Here's a compilable example:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned globalCounter = 0;

#define for(x)  for(x, ++globalCounter)

int main () {
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i);
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i);

    std::cout << globalCounter << '\n';
}
```

This outputs 20. However, existing code like

```
for (int i=0; i<x; ++i, foobar+=20)
```

will break as it now passes two arguments to the for-macro.

What you would need is a macro overloads or variadic macros. The latter is supported in C99 and C++11 derives it, so if you want the evil to happen:

```
unsigned globalCounter = 0;
#define for(...)  for(__VA_ARGS__, ++globalCounter)

#include <iostream>

void main () {
    int another = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i, ++another);
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i, ++another);

    std::cout << globalCounter << ' ' << another << '\n';
}
```

then

```
g++ --std=c++0x source.cc
./a.out
20 20
```

I do not support this. Macros may harm your children.

Comment: Make it variadic and the last snippet won't break it. `#define for(...)  for(__VA_ARGS__, ++globalCounter)`. (C++11).

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: But C++ does to my knowledge not have variadic macros, that's why I added a C99 answer.

Comment: Like I mentioned, variadic macros were added in C++11.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Cannot find it in n3242, through.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Oh, didn't know this. [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9588701/76722), thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the block does not belong to the `for` statement anymore. The transformation becomes

```
for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i)
{
   if (!RANDOM_CHANCE)
   {
      break;
   }
}

// unrelated to the 'for' above.
{
    if(i < 100) {
        std::cout << "Y";
    } else {
        std::cout << "N";
    }
}
```

Instead,  you could just write

```
#define for(...) for(__VA_ARGS__) if(RANDOM_CHANCE)
```

So the code becomes

```
for (int i=0; i < 100; ++i)
    if (RANDOM_CHANCE)
    {
        if(i < 100) {
            std::cout << "Y";
        } else {
            std::cout << "N";
        }
    }
```

(Note that I have used [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).)

---

And for the global_counter thing, if you can guarantee that the increament part will never be empty, then it's easy:

```
#define for(...) for(__VA_ARGS__, ++ global_counter)
```

Otherwise (e.g. there is `for(;;)` in the code), I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I think you can fix the first issue by adding an `else` to the macro (see my answer).